# How to combine or merge two internet connections in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, internet-connection

As I have new requirement in project, which is to combine or merge the multiple internet connection to get the higher bandwidth, so that it can speed up the request and response, downloading and uploading on server. Even I have searched a lot on SO regarding this but unable to find the relevant solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

The app name [SPEEDIFY](https://speedify.com/) uses this feature to combine multiple internet connections.

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Just dropping requirements "this is what I want" isn't appreciated. When you try something yourself, and you get stuck with a specific problem, we will gladly help. But please understand that this place is not intended to give guidance with the possibly many steps required to get you from your vision to a working program. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question please.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks. Next time I'll give attention to it :)

Answer (score 2):

speedify works by offloading the processing to a remote server.  It intercepts downstream traffic at a remote server and redirects the packets to two different IPs (for your two different internet connections) and the local app recombines them.  This can not be done without a remote server.